# iOS - Safari Content Blocker can't read data from NSUserDefaults

Tags: nsuserdefaults, ios9, ios-extensions, ios-app-group, safari-content-blocker

I've been working on a Content Blocking application for some time now. I have a switch in the main app that should turn of the blocking filter. The value of this switch is saved in an NSUserDefaults property that's enabled with App Groups so the blocking extension can read whether it's enabled or not (if blocking is enabled it returns a full json list and if not it returns an empty one).

On Simulator this works just fine, but when I start running it on a device (tested on 5s and 5c) the extension can't read the properties from the UserDefaults anymore (it always returns nil) and the application can't read the properties from the extension anymore.

I think it has something to do with the App Groups, but I can't seem to find any problems with that (it's enabled in Capibilities etc.) so I'm a bit lost. Has anyone ever had this problem? If so, were you able to fix it?

I'm using Xcode 7 beta, iOS 9 beta2 and Mac OS X Yosemite.

Comment: This was a known bug in the early iOS beta, but I am not sure if it has been fixed yet. Beta 5 is out as of August 6th. Have you tried it with that version?

Comment: The problem has not been fixed yet, I hope that it will be solved for the Golden Master.